# How to consume ASP.NET Core WebAPI using MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build a web application using ASP.NET Core Web API and MVC with Razor views.

Here is my code for the `TopicController`:

```
  public async Task'<'IResult'>' Index()
  {
      return Results.Ok(await _Data.GetAllTopics());
  }
```

Output of this controller is:

```
{ 
    "value": [
                 { 
                   "id": 1,
                   "topicName": "ACCESS MODIFIER",
                   "videoName": null,
                   "videoURL":null
                 },
                 {
                   "id": 2,
                   "topicName": "GENERICS",
                   "videoName": null,
                   "videoURL": null
                 }
             ],
    "statusCode": 200,
    "contentType": null
}
```

I am able display data if the return type of `Index()` is `IActionResult` for a complex object. But not sure how to interpret result from above `Index()` function.

I am new to front end, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Start by nuking `Results.Ok` from the code because this returns JSON. Change the return type of the action method to `ActionResult`, be sure to return `View`, then build the Razor page.

Comment: You are right, code return JSON and that is what I am trying to consume via Razor views, but don't know how to do that . I am trying to avoid changing my controller otherwise I will have to rewrite whole WebAPI logic.

Comment: If you need to consume JSON then you'll need to make an Ajax call from JS on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my code work. Instead of returning JSON I am retuning a view. However I have to do a local mapping of the objects.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{

List<Models.Topic> topics = new List<Models.Topic>();

  var result = await _Data.GetAllTopics();

foreach (var item in result)
{
  topics.Add(new Models.Topic
  {
    Id = item.Id,
    TopicName = item.TopicName,
    VideoName= item.VideoName,
    VideoURL = item.VideoURL
  });
}

return View(topics);
}
```